# file permission issue of my site

Tags: php, apache

I am facing a serious problem from today.
If I use filezilla ftp software, I can see owner/group of any php script (such as mysite.com/myphpscript.php) under public_html folder is set to 2707 2705. So if this php script create a file by

```
file_put_contents('/personal/testdata','This is test text');
```

Then the created file testdata in personal folder (public_html/personal) must have owner/group as 2707 2705. But surprisingly I can see that after creation testdata file, it's ownership is set to 99 99 (nobody).

If I transfer a php script from my pc to public_html folder by filezilla, its ownership is set to 2707 2705, but if this php script is creating a file by file_put_contents, ownership of this created file is automatically set as 99 99.

I asked server staff to resolve this issue, but they are continuously telling me that this is not due to server issue, this is php script issue. But I don't know why a php script, which ownership is 2707 2705, is creating file which ownership is 99 99?

Anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Apache does not use your FTP user. That's a pretty common set-up when PHP runs as Apache module. If you want a solution you'll first have to explain why it is a problem for you.

Comment: I guess this happens because the script is **executed** by user `nobody`, for security reasons. You should perform an explicit `chown`, provided that `nobody` is allowed to chown to you.

Comment: You cannot tell from simply what you see. The FTP server can apply maskerading to the permissions, can have pseudo virtual users, ... this question can only be answered properly by your provider.

Answer (score 1):

Files will be created by the user that's running apache. In most cases, that's `apache` or `nobody`. You will have to change the [owner](https://www.php.net/chown) and [group](https://www.php.net/chgrp) of the file. Also, to change permissions, you need to keep the [`umask`](https://www.php.net/umask) in mind.

Comment: How can I change the owner and group of the file. Please explain it elaborately. I have shared hosting and don't have access to shell. How can I do it by php or cpanel?

Comment: @stockBoi In general terms, it cannot be done. You cannot change file ownership with FTP and you cannot write code to take over other user's files. I insist: why do you want to do it in the first place?

Comment: stockBoi, see the links I put in? `chgrp` and `chown` do this.

Comment: @MueR So you can do e.g. `chown nobody /etc/passwd`? No, you cannot. It's like suggesting you can get a copy of the keys of any house you can't enter.

Comment: No, but you can change permissions on files you create. Seriously. Read. The. Docs.

Comment: because I can't create any file by php script in public_html folder as public_html folder has permission as 755. As 'nobody' is creating this file, it is unable to write the file in public_html folder directly and for security reason I can't set permission of public_html folder to 777

Comment: Correct. You want to create a folder in public_html via ftp, let's call it `personal`, chmod that to 777. You do not want your public_html world-writable.

Comment: Don't forget to mark one of the answers as the answer to your question .

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by PHP-scripts being run with the same user `99` as the webserver (Apache or other). To have PHP-scripts run as the account user, the webhost should use [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/5?q=node/10) or [FPM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php)

Comment: That's not true. Most shared hosting servers do this. They chroot the apache user, apply open_basedir and a host of other features to prevent a user from leaving their directory. Also, by running the server as apache, you can prevent PHP from making changes to your files, or email, if you set the permissions properly.

Comment: Well, I know. But I've also seen that broken on many occasions. IMO, FPM is a minimum for security.

Comment: How do they maintain a modest level of security then?

Comment: Assuming a typical PHP+Apache environment?

Comment: They fiddle with open_basedir and other settings. But it is rarely bullet-proof.

Comment: Apache+FPM is easy to setup, and you can `chmod 700 *.php` for better security.

Comment: Linux has SELinux, chroot and many other tools. Running PHP scripts as `nobody` doesn't automatically imply you can read stuff from other accounts.

Comment: My open_basedir is set on

Comment: @stockBoi: As you can see, there are many opinions on this. My preference after +15 years in webhosting is to have PHP run as your own user, so that you can chmod your PHP-files `700` meaning nobody else on the server has a chance to read their contents. In this way, all files created by PHP (like file-uploads) will be safely owned by your account. You should never have to `chmod 777` anything.

Comment: How can I run PHP as my own user?

Comment: Either the webhost starts using something like FPM or FastCGI (see links in post above), or you need to move to another webhost that does.